# Design an algorithm to find all the common elements in two sorted lists of numbers

Tags: algorithm, analysis

Design an algorithm to find all the common elements in two sorted lists of numbers.  E.g. for the lists 2, 4, 4, 4, 7 and 1, 2, 2, 6, 4, 4, 7 the output should be 2, 4, 4, 7 Which algorithmic design technique did you use and why? What is the maximum and minimum number of comparisons your algorithm makes if the lengths of the two given lists are m and n, respectively

```
 vector<int>  findCommon(vector<int> arr1, vector<int>arr2){
 vector<int> intersection;
 int n1 = arr1.size();
 int n2 = arr2.size();
 int k = 0, x = 0;
 while (x < n1 && k < n2) {
 if (arr1[x] > arr2[k]) {
 l++;
} else if (arr2[k] > arr1[x]) {
  k++;
} else {
  intersection.push_back(arr1[i]);
  x++;
  k++;
}
}
return intersection;
```

A Brute force algorithm was used as the design technique above. 
The complexity is O(m+n) because in the worst case, there would be no intersection between the two arrays, and we need to increment first index a total of m times and increment second index a total of n times, which is a total of m+n times.

Comment: You should at least specify what language are you trying to use and also what have you done so far!

Comment: i made some edit . put my solution . then judge me . its my first post on this site

Answer (score 3):

Start with two indices pointing to beginning of the arrays. If the elements pointed by these indices are same, then it is a common element, and we advance both the pointers. If one element is smaller, then advance that pointer (in hope of finding the next equal element). Continue this until any one of the two indices reaches their end.

This is the most efficient algorithm since the two lists are already sorted.

Comment: I know this question is stupid old but as a newbie to algorithms I just wanted to take the time to say thank you for actually having not only a constructive answer but also taking the time to speak on how it's affective. I hate that as I go through the internet while working on my practice problems anytime that I connect to a SO question that is similar it has tons of downvotes and a very unhealthy side of salt.